# string and select column from sql

Tags: mysql, string

I am trying to select all name from a table and use use `str.find` for find in a sentence but just select first record.

```
     executeQuery("SELECT Name FROM sql_namestable;");
                char aName[128];
                strcpy(aName, getString("Name").c_str());
                std::string str ("Deadname anothername testname killername poolname"); //for example
                std::string str2 (aName);
                std::size_t found = str.find(str2);
                dbg_msg("names","%s", aName);

                if (found!=std::string::npos)
                    {
                         // code
                    }
```

Result:

```
[names]: Dead
```

My tables columns;

```
Dead, Killer, Test, Pool;
```

This dead is my first row in my sql table. How I can get all rows of column names in result?

Comment: sqlserver  or mysql  ????

Comment: mysql,
and i'm using wampserver in windows 10

Answer (score 0):

In mysql  You can use group_concat

```
SELECT group_concate(Name) FROM sql_namestable;
```

Comment: SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Name) from %s_namestable;
now show this error:
MySQL Error: MySQL_ResultSet::getString: invalid value of 'columnIndex'

for this line:
strcpy(aName, getString("Name").c_str());

Comment: @KingGta   what do you mean eaxplain better .. ( from %s_nametbale  is not allowed )  ..you can't use wildchar for table name

Comment: sorry for that %s

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Name) from sql_namestable;

Comment: @KingGta   .. your comment is like my answer .. using the sql in my answer you have errors ..? problems?   . i don't understand you comment  ..